# How to add static information to dynamic data in Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, filter, google-sheets

I'm importing data into Google Sheets and then adding static information to it. I'd like my static data to be kept in alignment with a dynamic - is this possible? Is a script still required? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: With scripting, many things are possible. It'll be of much help if you can give an example sheet with sample data for us to try.

Comment: here you go! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11j3-SUlzqGRRNC1WcCUloBnxVogQxOWPsNzo_OEprDs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your data structure, but there is a way with **`VLOOKUP`** formula

- **https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function**

Comment: thank you! im going to play around with scripts tonight, but i put together an example workbook for you to use.

the data on the left is mostly being imported and the data columns on the right are for adding notes. 

the goal: to sort orders in descending order - newest on top, while retaining notes that are entered to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already find your solution to the problem? It sounds like you sort be able to sort the data with filters and still keep your note columns aligned.

Comment: hello! no, i haven't yet. the vlookup isn't quite what i need.
ive tried to sort columns, but this breaks my formulas and makes everything wacky. were you able to check out my example workbook?

Answer (score 0):

this script could perhaps help:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z");

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
}
```

---

- `Sheet1` = name of the sheet
- `A1:Z` = range to be sorted
- `column: 2` = column B
- `ascending: false` = descending

[image: 0]